# Javascript: getting location.search out of any url?

Tags: jquery, url

i know top.location.search retruns **?key=anything&blabla=foobar** of my current url. I wonder how i can get the search value out of any url?

if I have e.g. 
$goToURL = 'http://www.anydomain.com/hello/?path=xyz
how can i get ?path=xyz out there and save it to a variable?

regards matt

Comment: I don't think you mean to have that $ there. Technically it's legal but this isn't PHP and the dollar isn't a variable identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edited based on @Nick's comment]

```
alert('http://www.anydomain.com/hello/?path=xyz'.split('?', 1)[1]);
```

Comment: +1 - Should be `.split('?', 1)` though, in case there's a `?` later :)

Comment: Nice one, Nick. Can a '?' even legitimately occur more than once? In any case, I won't edit that in, as your comment does the trick :)

Comment: @karim79: Yes, I've seen URLs with several `?`s in the past.

Comment: It can happen, but any URL with a non-encoded ? after the first ? is malformed. Some browsers (servers? languages?) will ignore anything following the second one. Others just discard the subsequent ?s.

Comment: This will also include any #anchor at the end of the URL, it won't just be the query string

Comment: @mathiregister - Be advised, @Gareth's solution is the better one.

Answer (score 2):

The location properties like .search are also available on `<a>` elements. So, create an `<a>` element dynamically and set it's href, and you should be able to access those properties.

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = "..."
console.log(a.search)
```

Comment: +1 - does it exactly like the browser would, ignoring hashes etc.